# Is this simple ViewModel example to share data between Activities correct?

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I'm trying to implement a ViewModel to share data between Activities.
Because I am a beginner, the answers I found on the Internet mainly concern fragments
and are a little complicated for my current level.
So taking inspiration from different sources, I wrote the following simple solution which seems to work.
I would like to know if this code is correct because I read somewhere that a ViewModel cannot be shared between two UIs

**ViewModel Class**

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var ctr by mutableStateOf(0)
}
```

**Navigator**

```
@Composable
fun Navigateur() {
    val myNavController = rememberNavController()
    val myViewModel = viewModel<MyViewModel>()

    NavHost(navController = myNavController, startDestination = "ecran1" ){
        composable(route = "ecran1"){
            Ecran1(myNavController,myViewModel)
        }
        composable(route = "ecran2"){
            Ecran2(myViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity 1**

```
@Composable
fun Ecran1(monNavController: NavController, monViewModel: MyViewModel) {
    Column (horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        Text(text = monViewModel.ctr.toString(),fontSize = 30.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Cyan)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
        Button(onClick = { monViewModel.ctr++  }) {
            Text(text = "  Incrémenter  ")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
        Button(onClick = { monNavController.navigate("ecran2") }) {
            Text(text = "  Ecran 2  ")
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity 2**

```
@Composable
fun Ecran2(monViewModel: MyViewModel) {
    Column (horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        Text(text = monViewModel.ctr.toString(), fontSize = 30.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Cyan)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))
        Button(onClick = { monViewModel.ctr++ }) {
            Text(text = "  Incrémenter  ")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm gonna correct you on the term **activity** in a fully Jetpack Compose project you only have **one activity** which is `MainActivity` the composable ones are called **Screens** (des écrans) keep that in mind.

> I read somewhere that a ViewModel cannot be shared between two UIs

It's better to have separate `viewmodels` for each **Screen** yeah but in certain cases it's okay to have a `SharedViewModel`.

Now the best way i would do it is not how you did it, instead i would have just one instance of `viewModel` created outside `NavHost`(which you already did) and instead of passing that instance to both my screens i would pass the actual `ctr` value as normal `Int` parameter and that has benefits like you only create on instance of `ctr` which will help in debugging..etc and in Testing you can pass a fake one just for test reasons but this is more of an advance topic.

Comment: Thanks @Ayman for the clarification regarding Activity and Screen. This is all new to me and there is so much to learn.

If I understood your suggestion correctly. I pass the value of ctr to my screens. I supose like this:

 `Ecran1(myNavController,myViewModel.ctr)`
 
 `Ecran2(myViewModel.ctr)`
 
  and in the screnns side:
 
 `fun Ecran1(monNavController: NavController, ctr: Int) {...}`
 and
 `fun Ecran2(ctr: Int) {..}`
 
 That way, Ecran1() and Ecran2() will not be able to modifie the common value of ctr

Comment: @A.Oumnad yup thats it you pass them like. if you want to apply the concept that only viewModel should change the value of ctr try to have two variables in viewmodels one is private mutableState that only viewmodel can change and one is a public State that you expose to the UI

Comment: @A.Oumnad btw if find this helpful please consider make in it as right answer

Comment: you read somewhere? Just like how Palpatine somehow returned?